# @JsonUnwrapped creates non-null object even when all fields are null

Tags: json, spring-boot, jackson

I ran into this problem in the context of SpringBoot, but it seems to be just a Jackson issue.

I have a DataObject which has several fields.  The DataObject is contained within a Model.  All the fields of DataObject are optional.  But if all the fields are null, then I want the dataoObject itself to be null, but that doesn't seem to be the way it works.

Here my sample code

```
@Getter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
public class TestContract {

    private String field1;

    @JsonUnwrapped
    @Valid
    private DataObject dataObject;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        //language=JSON
        String json = "{ \"field1\" :  \"value1\"}";
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        TestContract contract = mapper.readValue(json, TestContract.class);
        System.out.println("contract: " + contract);
    }
}


@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class DataObject {
    private String nested1;
    private String nested2;
}
```

The output I end up with is

```
contract: TestContract(field1=value1, dataObject=DataObject(nested1=null, nested2=null))
```

Is there any way to have the object end up as null?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to the fact that the [`JsonUnwrapped`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonUnwrapped.html) annotation has the `enabled` property with a default `true` value, so even if the property `dataObject` is not present in your json message an empty `dataObject` object will be created in any case. To solve the issue, you could use a `JsonUnwrapped(enabled = false)` annotation or you could directly delete the `JsonUnwrapped` annotation.

**Update :** due to the fact that according to the project's specifics is it not possible to erase the `JsonUnwrapped` annotation, a workaround is the creation of a custom deserializer leaving untouched the main code like below :

```
@Getter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
public class TestContract {

    private String field1;

    @JsonUnwrapped
    private DataObject dataObject;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException, IOException {
        //language=JSON
        String json = "{ \"field1\" :  \"value1\"}";
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        TestContract contract = mapper.readValue(json, TestContract.class);
        System.out.println("contract: " + contract);
    }
}


@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@JsonDeserialize(using = DataObjectDeserializer.class)
public class DataObject {
    private String nested1;
    private String nested2;
}

public class DataObjectDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<DataObject> {
    @Override
    public DataObject deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext dc) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
        String nested1 = node.get("nested1").asText();
        String nested2 = node.get("nested2").asText();
        DataObject dataObject = new DataObject();
        dataObject.setNested1(nested1);
        dataObject.setNested2(nested2);
        return dataObject;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Not sure what you mean by directly deleting the `JsonUnwrapped` annotation.  Obviously, not using that annotation would fix the problem.  But I need it for other reasons.  But I will try running with `enabled=false`

Comment: Hi I'm afraid this didn't work.  It is always setting the object to null.  I don't fully understand what `enabled=false` does.  The documentation is sparse, but says that it is only for some very specific situations.  From the doc: `Property that is usually only used when overriding (masking) annotations, using mix-in annotations.`

Comment: @PeterKronenberg Hello, as a workaround I implemented a custom DataObjectDeserializer so with the `@JsonDeserialize` and `Setter` annotations over the DataObject class for me it solves the problem. If you think it can be useful to you I add it to my answer.

Comment: Yes, I ended up having to write a custom deserializer

Comment: I thought I had it working, but it doesn't.  I have a deserializer similar to what you wrote, except I have the condition of `if (nested1 == null && nested2 == null) { return null}`.  But the problem is that the deserializer is not being called even if my input has the `nested1` and `nested2` fields (since I'm using `JsonUnwrapped`, the input does not have it wrapped in a DataObject key).  Not sure what's going on.  It's like `JsonUnwrapped` is being ignored

Comment: P.S. You forgot the @JsonUnwrapped annotation in your sample code

Comment: @PeterKronenberg Probably I'm missing something, in my version code I deleted just the `Valid` annotation in the `TestContract` class and added `Setter` annotation in the `DataObject` class, so the `JsonUnwrapped` annotation still remains untouched in the `TestContract` class. I'm using jackson 2.12.2.

Comment: Well, I still need the `@Valid` annotation, because there are other validations that need to be done.  Are you saying you have a `@Setter` annotation in the Contract class for the `DataObject`?  Or a @Setter in the `DataObject` itself?    And if your Json input doesn't have any of the fields in `DataObject`, then `DataObject` is null?  Can you post exactly what you have.

Comment: @PeterKronenberg, I added my code , all classes are in the same package in a generic maven project (no spring-boot).

Comment: I tried your code and yes, the object is null in this case, but it doesn't seem to work to populate the object. For example, if the Json string is `String json = "{ \"field1\" :  \"value1\", \"nested1\":  \"nested1Value\", \"nested2\": \"nested2Value\"}";`. 
It does work if I wrap the object as `"dataObject": {}`, but that defeats the purpose of `@JsonUnwrapped`

Comment: Any other thoughts on this?  It doesn't seem to be honoring @JsonUnwrapped