# Can Jackson accept both wrapped and unwrapped Json when using JsonUnwrapped

Tags: json, jackson

I have a class like this:

```
...
@JsonUnwrapped
private DataObject dataObject;
...
```

Data object is

```
@Getter
public class DataObject {
    private String nested1;
    private String nested2;
}
```

Obviously, this will work if my Json input is

```
{
   "nested1" : "nestedValue1", 
   "nested2" : "nestedValue2"
}
```

Is there a way to make it flexible so that it can accept both versions?
But what if I want it to also be able to accept

```
{
   "dataObject: {
      "nested1" : "nestedValue1", 
      "nested2" : "nestedValue2"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the code of your `TestContract` class from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68795815/jsonunwrapped-creates-non-null-object-even-when-all-fields-are-null) below :

```
public class TestContract {
    private String field1;

    @JsonUnwrapped
    private DataObject dataObject;
}
```

One way to solve the problem is to write a custom deserializer for your `TestContract` class that will use the following lombok annotations and the `@JsonDeserialize` annotation :

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonDeserialize(using = TestContractDeserializer.class)
public class TestContract {
    private String field1;

    @JsonUnwrapped
    private DataObject dataObject;
}
```

The custom deserializer will check the `field1` property and after will check if the two `nested1` and `nested2` properties are nested or not inside the `dataObject` property covering both cases you presented :

```
public class TestContractDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<TestContract> {

    @Override
    public TestContract deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext dc) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
        //read the field1 property
        String field1 = node.get("field1").asText();
        JsonNode dataObjectNode = node.get("dataObject");
        //check if properties are nested or not
        if (dataObjectNode != null) {
            node = dataObjectNode;
        }
        String nested1 = node.get("nested1").asText();
        String nested2 = node.get("nested2").asText();
        DataObject dataObject = new DataObject();
        dataObject.setNested1(nested1);
        dataObject.setNested2(nested2);
        TestContract testContract = new TestContract();
        testContract.setDataObject(dataObject);
        testContract.setField1(field1);
        return testContract;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to have a custom deserializer for the Contract class because the DataObject class might appear in several places and I want its usage to be a bit more automatic

Comment: @PeterKronenberg Then you can visit the tree storing the parent and see if the childs are like those you are looking for.